# Categories defined by diagram schemes

Tags: category-theory

I was reading the *Tôhoku Paper* and when I got to the part of categories defined by diagram schemes I couldn't get the point of it.

What's the point of imposing the commutativity relations separately? I cannot find the difference between this definition and a category of functors from a "diagram" category with the commutative conditions already imposed.

What are the advantages of the diagram schemes?

Comment: A diagram scheme can be seen as a syntactic object of the <theory of categories>, while a category is a semantic one (a model). 
It is also something like a *presentation* of a category, The directed graph part takes the role of 'generators' and the commutativity relations are the 'relations'.